# Nested scroll view on top of backdrop menu Material theme Android

Tags: android, material-ui

I am having an issue with the display of the backdrop menu from material-ui for android together with a nested scroll view which comes on top of the backdrop when scrolling, I have been trying to use the elevation property on different elements hoping that it will work but I got no where;

this is the layout for **main_fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Backdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="88dp">

        <include layout="@layout/backdrop_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="8dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menu_icon"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_lay"
            layout="@layout/main_menu_layout" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

then **main_menu_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linLayMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreateUserMainMenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/button_create_user_main_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddProductMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/button_add_product_main_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonTransferProductMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/button_transfer_product_main_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowAccountQRMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/button_show_account_qr_main_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonQRCodeScanMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_qrcode_scan_main_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_one" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_two" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test" />


</LinearLayout>
```

then **backdrop_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemLogin"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backdrop_menu_login" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemCommercial"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backdrop_menu_commercial" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemOption2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backdrop_menu_option2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemProducts"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backdrop_menu_products" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemLogout"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/backdrop_menu_logout" />

</merge>
```

in the following picture, in red are buttons that should not be on top of the backdrop menu, when i scroll in the main menu layout i want it to go under the backdrop menu; thanks in advance

[image: display menu issue]

Answer (score 0):

Try using CollapsingToolbarLayout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="88dp">

                <include layout="@layout/backdrop_menu" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.Provenance.Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menu_icon"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_lay"
            layout="@layout/main_menu_layout" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however using Collapsing toolbar it makes the backdrop menu behaviour break so that it always shows its layout;

Comment: do you want to keep the backdrop menu always visible when the NestedScrollView is being scrolled?

Comment: no, the behavior that i currently have is that when i click the hamburger icon the backdrop menu shows up by pushing the nested scroll view, however if i use the collapsing toolbar to keep the backdrop inside, it simply shows all the time, and the hamburger icon just pushes an empty background

Comment: you can wrap the backdrop menu with RelativeLayout and set parameter animateLayoutChanges="true", then show hide it. The RelativeLayout should be inside the NestedScrollView child